# Semantic release using prerelease on beta branch

Tags: git, semantic-release

When using `semantic-release` and doing `beta` pre-releases.

https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/workflow-configuration#pre-release-branches

[image]

They say that if the last version on `main` is `1.0.0`, if you push a breaking change to `beta`, it will release a `2.0.0-beta.1`. And if you subsequently add whatever type of commits to beta, it will increment only the beta counter.

And what if you start with a non-breaking change commit?

Then it will create a `1.1.0-beta.1`, right?

And what if you add a breaking change commit later? Will it change from `1.1.0-beta.1` to `2.0.0-beta.1`?